# How to Pair Microsoft Mouse 4000 with a different Receiver?

Tags: wireless-mouse

We have two Microsoft Mouse 4000's. One is in good shape but has a burnt out nano-receiver.  The other one is in bad shape with a good nano-receiver.

How can I pair the good nano receiver with the good mouse?

I realize that I could just swap the top-covers, but the good mouse has a better clicker that I'd like to retain.  So I just want to re-use the nano-receiver.

Can I repair them somehow?

Comment: haha - I googled up this question (apparently I still have it) and tried to upvote it!  Then I realized it was my own question!  haha - 2 years and no responses except this here comment.